# flutter showing black screen while launching the app in real device

Tags: android, flutter, windows, dart

i tried to install flutter in my mobile using USB Debugging. if i run the app using the run button from the IDE, it displays a black screen. But i run using `flutter run` command it working, but hot-reload is not working. what is the issue here? i tried both Windows and Ubuntu, both having the same issue.

Code is just the Boiler plate code, nothing i have changed in it.

i just tried to run the boiler plate code, just to confirm everything is working fine. But it showing a blank screen while using run button from android studio IDE. What i need to change in the IDE config or i missed something?

Comment: Please write your code located inside main() here